# Blueprism Isn't Returning Database Results

Tags: sql, database, oracle, blueprism

I have a Blueprism object which opens an Oracle database connection and runs a SQL script. This object has been working correctly for the past 12 months. I am developing a new process and the object isn't bringing back any results. If I run the SQL select against the database it returns results. When Blueprism runs it doesn't bring back any results.
I am manually connecting as the same user account.

I cannot provide SQL but it is a standard Select with where clauses.
Stack Overflow is not allowing me to upload a photo of my object.

Comment: Well, it's hard to answer that question, as it's just a troubleshooting one. 

Does the code return any exceptions?
Does the simplest SQL code works correctly, e.g. "select * from Table1 limit 1"?
Does the same querry you used for a year works here too?
Are there any calculations inside of querry? Are they right?

Comment: Unfortunately it is very difficult. No exceptions, just returns no results. Yes other queries work. Yes old jobs are running fine. There aren't any calculations. One potential issue is that I need to reference the schema before one of the tables. Could that cause an issue?

Comment: Well, if other querries work, and this one doesn't, then probably an issue comes from it, right?

If so, then you may try to rebuild it step by step, to see on which step it stops working in BP.

Comment: Blueprism seems to be ignoring the date portion of the Sql query. Basically, I have a where clause ci.date >= '01/Sep/2019' , this makes no difference whatsoever and is behaving as if it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was linked to how Blueprism queries dates. I needed to amend SQL query to use this syntax

```
between to_date('01/Feb/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('31/Dec/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: `'31/Dec/2017'`  is a dangerous date format - e.g. when run from my computer that will simply fail. Avoid localized month names in DATE values. Using `to_date('31/12/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` would be more robust

Comment: Thanks for that, when my job gets to production it will be taking dates in as variables (these are dummy values to get the job up and running)